# Is there a way to get information about an auto reported bug?

Tags: bug-reporting, apport

When I try suspend to RAM and resume, system freezes. On next session system detects the problem and gives me a way to report it to developers. This problem has been there a long time. Is there a way to know what developers are doing for the issue if anything? Is there a bug tracker for such issues? I would like to use suspend to RAM, since my computer uses relatively lot electricity and I want to save it while I take a break.

[image]

Comment: I made the question more general since I also want to know this but for other problems too.

Comment: Might help to look into $cd /var/crash/

Comment: @Karan how does that tell us what new information may have appeared from an auto reported bug?